# What are the angle brackets "<…>" in an Obj-C class interface for?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, objc-protocol

Can anyone tell me what the angle brackets `<...>` in an Objective-C class interface do? Like this one (from http://snipt.net/robhawkes/cocoa-class-interface):

```
@interface MapMeViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, 
            MKReverseGeocoderDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> { ... }
```

From my view they look like some sort of type declaration (considering my previous experience in PHP and JavaScript), like we're making sure `MapMeViewController` is a `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, `MKReverseGeocoderDelegate`, `MKMapViewDelegate`, or `UIAlertViewDelegate`

Documentation about the `@interface` syntax don't seem to mention this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The angle brackets in a class interface definition indicates the protocols that your class is conforming to.

A protocol is almost like an interface in Java or C#, with the addition that methods in an Objective-C protocol can be optional.

Additionaly in Objective-C you can declare a variable, argument or instance variable to conform to several protocols as well. Example

```
NSObject<NSCoding, UITableViewDelegate> *myVariable;
```

In this case the class must be `NSObject` or a subclass (only `NSProxy` and its subclasses would fail), and it must also conform to both `NSCoding` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

In Java or C# this would only be possible by actually declaring said class.

Answer (score 9):

The angle brackets indicate a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html). They're analogous to interfaces in other languages.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use them in code like a cast to tell the complier to expect an object that conforms to a particular protocol.

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.noteFetcher sections] objectAtIndex:section];
```

Answer (score 4):

Apple documentation reports the use of brackets; see [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf) on the chapter 4, on "Adopting a Protocol".

> Adopting a protocol is similar in some ways to declaring a superclass. Both assign methods to the class. The superclass declaration assigns it inherited methods; the protocol assigns it methods declared in the protocol list. A class is said to adopt a formal protocol if in its declaration it lists the protocol within angle brackets after the superclass name:
>
> ```
> @interface ClassName : ItsSuperclass < protocol list >
> ```
>
> Categories adopt protocols in much the same way:
>
> ```
> @interface ClassName ( CategoryName ) < protocol list >
> ```